# Compositor: File output with custom range

Tags: compositing-nodes

I would like to have multiple file output nodes in my comp scene and want to render seperate ranges for each node. Is this possible ?

thank you

Comment: Unfortunately no. You might be able to do something like what you want with multiple scenes though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a frame change callback and drive the mute of those output nodes with script:

```
import bpy

def frame_change_handler(scene):
    nodes = scene.node_tree.nodes
    nodes['File Output 1'].mute = not (15 < scene.frame_current < 50)
    nodes['File Output 2'].mute = not (45 < scene.frame_current < 55)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_change_handler)
```

Adjust the names of the nodes and the ranges like you want. You can also insert a driver to mute property in outliner dataview but such drivers on nodes do not update correctly, that's why it needs to be frame change handler.

If you need to change something in the script and want to re-run it call `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()` in console first. Enjoy:)